# Hook dlsym in AIX system

Tags: hook, aix, dlsym

I want to use LDR_PRELOAD to hook dlsym, but I could not find a way to get the dlsym address in libc.a. I try to use nlist with libc.a, but it did not work.

Is that any way to get the dlsym by symbol table?

Comment: Extract shr.o from /usr/lib/libdl.a, then use nm or dump on shr.o Anyways, on AIX you won't be able to hijack library functions this way.

Comment: actually it should be able to hijack dlsym, use loadquery you can get libc.a base address, may be parse symbol table, then can calculate the dlsym address?